# Visual Studio 2015 compiled ASP.NET MVC site template on Mono - System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nginx, mono

Recently I've been trying out Mono for hosting ASP.NET MVC apps and when trying to run template application built with Visual Studio 15 I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException No process is associated with this
>   object.

Stack trace:

```
 at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState (System.Diagnostics.Process+State state) [0x0001e] in <affe4060066c42de8cdd6027cdb92b56>:0 
 at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_HasExited () [0x0000b] in <affe4060066c42de8cdd6027cdb92b56>:0 
 at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState (System.Diagnostics.Process+State state) [0x00093] in <affe4060066c42de8cdd6027cdb92b56>:0 
 at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_ExitCode () [0x00000] in <affe4060066c42de8cdd6027cdb92b56>:0 
 at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_ExitCode () 
 at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.InternalExecWaitWithCapture (System.String cmd, System.String currentDir, System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection tempFiles, System.String& outputName, System.String& errorName) [0x000f1] in <affe4060066c42de8cdd6027cdb92b56>:0 
 at System.CodeDom.Compiler.Executor.ExecWaitWithCapture (System.IntPtr userToken, System.String cmd, System.String currentDir, System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection tempFiles, System.String& outputName, System.String& errorName) [0x00007] in <affe4060066c42de8cdd6027cdb92b56>:0 
 at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.Compile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String compilerFullPath, System.String arguments, System.String& outputFile, System.Int32& nativeReturnValue) [0x00071] in <57d777233c3f47cfbcc22a12ce3dc52b>:0 
 at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.FromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00170] in <57d777233c3f47cfbcc22a12ce3dc52b>:0 at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00048] in <57d777233c3f47cfbcc22a12ce3dc52b>:0 
 at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00014] in <affe4060066c42de8cdd6027cdb92b56>:0 
 at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x002f5] in <80d482637b7943f8b4edcf91864a2ce4>:0 
 at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00008] in <80d482637b7943f8b4edcf91864a2ce4>:0 
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, System.Boolean debug) [0x00264] in <80d482637b7943f8b4edcf91864a2ce4>:0 
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, System.Boolean debug) [0x0011c] in <80d482637b7943f8b4edcf91864a2ce4>:0 
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00063] in <80d482637b7943f8b4edcf91864a2ce4>:0 
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00040] in <80d482637b7943f8b4edcf91864a2ce4>:0 
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00006] in <80d482637b7943f8b4edcf91864a2ce4>:0 
 at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00179] in <80d482637b7943f8b4edcf91864a2ce4>:0
```

I am using FastCGI Mono Server on Nginx, OS is Debian stretch.

To check if this is a server configuration problem I deployed a website I created with Visual Studio 13 and it works without any problems. To set up the servers I was mostly following [mono docs for nginx](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/nginx/).

First problem I had with the project created in VS15 was:

> Could not find file "/var/www/html/mono/bin\roslyn\csc.exe".

So I used the MONO_IOMAP=all setting (not sure if this is a proper way to fix this). Afterwards I am getting the exception I mentioned before.

Both sites (the working one built with VS13 and the template one) target .NET Framework 4.5. The only big difference I could find in Web.config files is this section (found in the new site):

```
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
```

I suspect that this issue is somehow connected with the fact that VS15 is using the Roslyn compiler. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the error message carefully and compare VS2013/2015 projects, you should see that the CompilerPlatform bit is the culprit.

Microsoft designs that for .NET mainly so it does not work quite well on Mono. Either you remove it from your project in favor of Mono or fully switch to .NET Core.

Comment: I see. .NET Core seems good enough. I guess it doesn't have a full functionality of .NET framework, so do you have any list detailing what's missing?